# How to delete and rename the file or folder in IOS Box V2 Api

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, box

I need to rename and delete the file or folder in box API from my IOS APP.I'm fetching all the files from box and showing in my app . I need to rename and delete those files from my App.  please suggest me .

Where i'm using the following to delete the file in box ,

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID?recursive=true  \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
   -X DELETE
```

How to rename the folder ?as well as Delete is also not working with the above url?

https://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-delete-a-folder

Comment: rename and delete the file or folder in box means? explain

Comment: I'm fetching all the files from box and showing in my app . I need to rename and delete those files from my App. I renamed the files from my app in dropbox, as in the same way i need to rename the files in box.

Comment: Explaining means that you should update your post and write more clearly asap. Make your question is not hard to understand. If you are viewer who viewed your question, what do you think about your question!

Comment: @VietHung did you understand the question now ?

Comment: What error message are you getting when you try to delete?

Comment: https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/210805140?recursive=true&access_token=8886786ffuf&DELETE Like this I'm passing the values,No error but it's not deleting .please help me if any mistake in passing parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for deleting .

```
NSString *str;
    if ([type isEqualToString:@"folder"])
    {
        str =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/%@?recursive=true&access_token=%@",folder_id,str_access_token];

    }
    else
    {
        str =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.box.com/2.0/files/%@?access_token=%@&If-Match=%@",folder_id,str_access_token,etag];

    }
    ASIFormDataRequest *postParams = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
    [postParams setRequestMethod:@"DELETE"];
    [postParams startAsynchronous];
    postParams.delegate = self ;
    postParams.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"DeleteFolder" forKey:@"id"];

    NSLog(@"Url is ---> %@",postParams.url);
    NSLog(@"response string is-----> %@",postParams.responseString);
```

Comment: You are not using Box iOS SDK

Answer (score 0):

Deletion is supper easy, coz there are APIs for this specify.

```
// For folder
BoxFoldersRequestBuilder * builder = [[BoxFoldersRequestBuilder alloc] initWithRecursiveKey:YES];
[boxFoldersResourceManager deleteFolderWithID:identifier
                               requestBuilder:builder
                                      success:successCallback
                                      failure:failureCallback];

// For file
[boxFilesResourceManager deleteFileWithID:identifier
                           requestBuilder:nil
                                  success:successCallback
                                  failure:failureCallback];
```

And renaming.

```
// For folder
BoxFoldersRequestBuilder *builder = [[BoxFoldersRequestBuilder alloc] init];
builder.name = newName;
[boxFoldersResourceManager editFolderWithID:file.identifier
                             requestBuilder:builder
                                    success:successCallback
                                    failure:failureCallback];
// For file
BoxFilesRequestBuilder *builder = [[BoxFilesRequestBuilder alloc] init];
builder.name = newName;
[boxFilesResourceManager editFileWithID:file.identifier
                         requestBuilder:builder
                                success:successCallback
                                failure:failureCallback];
```